# How do I update html element in a string inside an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a hard time doing something that seems really simple.
I have a javascript object:

```
var main = {
    pages : {
        "123" : {
            "content": "<div><p>The div</p></div><nav><p>The nav</p></nav>",
            "foo":"bar"
        },
        "456" : {
            "content": "<div><p>The div</p></div><nav><p>The nav</p></nav>",
            "foo":"bar"
        }
    }
};
```

I'm trying the following code:

```
$(function(){
        var p = main.pages;
        $.each(p,function(i,el){
            var c = p[i].content;
            var newc = $(c).find('nav').html('<p>New content</p>');
            //console.log(c);
            //console.log(newc);
        });
        //console.log(p)
});
```

To make my object look like:

```
var main = {
    pages : {
        "123" : {
            "content": "<div><p>The div</p></div><nav><p>New content</p></nav>",
            "foo":"bar"
        },
        "456" : {
            "content": "<div><p>The div</p></div><nav><p>New content</p></nav>",
            "foo":"bar"
        }
    }
};
```

But I'm having a hard time doing it. What am I missing?

I have set up the former example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmmtz/)

I do understand that it's generally not a good idea trying to manipulate strings as dom elements but I have no other choice since the object comes from a RESTful server and it doesn't make much sense to inject the html in the current page for that.

Comment: If I run the above code i get `Object
123: Object
content: "<div><p>The div</p></div><nav><p>The nav</p></nav>"
foo: "bar"
456: Object
content: "<div><p>The div</p></div><nav><p>The nav</p></nav>"
foo: "bar"` - so it does what you want in your question

Comment: You have a js object and you are trying to generate the same? can you please clarify?

Comment: Look again, the strings are not the same. In the expected object, the html inside the nav tag is different, changing from "the nav" to "new content".

Comment: may i know what actually u want it above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually [build the HTML in jQuery without appending it into the DOM](http://jsfiddle.net/wmmtz/1/).

```
$(function () {
    var p = main.pages;
    //a temporary div
    var div = $('<div>');
    $.each(p, function (i, el) {
        //append to div, find and replace the HTML
        div.append(p[i].content).find('nav').html('<p>New content</p>');
        //turn back into a string and store
        p[i].content = div.html();
        //empty the div for the next operation
        div.empty();
    });
    console.log(p);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved the day!!

Answer (score 1):

Because `$(p[i].content)` is not one element but two, so based on your code:

```
var tmp = $(p[i].content);
tmp.eq(1).html('<p>new content');
console.log(tmp.html());
```

Comment: In fact, since I'm getting content inside a loop, I just have one element each time.
I didn't test it but I believe it also works since it's similar to Joseph answers.
Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Robyflc: Put `$(main.pages['123'].content)` in a console you will find it returns a set with 2 elements, with `<nav>` as the root element of the second. This will cause the fallow `.find('nav')` is searching the child nodes of `<nav>`, so it wouldn't match anything.

Comment: I'm sorry. I completely misunderstood what you meant at first.